# how to write a html5?

Tags: html

what i should inorder right a html5 program which will communicate withe client and replies to the server.in which platform it becomes easy either in c# or javascript

Comment: If you aren't sure whether to use C# or Javascript, I doubt you're ready to use either.

Comment: no i asked which will better and easy to do.i am use to .net so can i use c# itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 (now just referred to as HTML) is not a programming language. It is exactly the same as HTML (4) but with a few new tags and a required doctype of `<!doctype html>`. That is it. You can use the canvas tag to create some awesome javascript good-ness (which may be what you are looking for) due to some awesome new javascript API's such as websockets, but HTML(5) itself does not do this.

Comment: k fine.see i need to write a code using html5 so that it will communicate with the server and gives a reply to the client  this is my assignment.so what i should be learning in order do this.can u explain it in detail about this.

Comment: Like I said. HTML 5 does NOT do this. JavaScript would be your best client side script to contact the server. Then you can use whatever technology you want on the server to receive and process that request, such as PHP, asp etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do - which is put together a HTML/Javascript front end which can communicate with a C# backend, I suggest using jQuery ajax or similar to call C# methods:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/to/your/File.aspx/SomeMethod",
    data: "{ yourData: 'data' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        // Successful
    },
    error: function() {
        // Unsuccessful
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have serious doubts if he knows what he wants, or at least he gives this impression by not even trying to elaborate on the problem