# How to write html5 code for

Tags: html

how can i write a html5 prototype which must be able to communicate which the server and reply back to the  client.this is the task that is i need to design a prototype which will be able to communicate with the server

Comment: HTML5 cannot do this. JavaScript can.

Comment: What do you mean by 'prototype'?

Comment: This question is un-answerable in its current state. Are you talking about using web sockets, or something like AJAX?

Comment: i am asking like wht i can do inorder to creta e a prototype using html5 and javascript which will be able to send a msg to the server.

Comment: You need to do a search for "web sockets" or "AJAX", do some research and then ask a more targeted question if so required.

Comment: This looks kind of familiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817055/how-to-write-a-html5 You need to be a bit more specific (do you want real-time communication? (I think that's what benhowdle89's answer has) or would AJAX polling be ok? (in which case, see e.g. this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499/ajax-polling )), or try something and tell us how it didn't work. Reposting the same thing will rarely get you a useful answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.indicthreads.com/1525/building-real-time-web-applications-using-html-5-web-sockets/